# What is the prefered way to write next_ds on an Airflow template?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

Some template variables that were quite useful in previous versions of airflow are now deprecated in favor of more general variables.
However, I'm not sure how to emulate the previous template variables. For example, how to use the available constructs such as `{{ds}}` or `{{data_interval_start }}`, to create `{{next_ds}}`, for example.

[Here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) is where we can find the current and deprecated airflow template variables.

Comment: next_ds = `{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 1) }}`

Comment: @Emma. The `ds_add` macro simply adds one day to the `ds`. The `next_ds` is a lot more clever than that as it takes the schedule_interval into account. I don't think your suggestion is a replacement.

Answer (score 6):

In most cases I think this works: `{{ data_interval_end | ds }}`.

The end of the data interval should be the start of the next data interval which should be the same as the next execution date unless there is some sort of lag on the dag between the execution date and the data window. The `| ds` part just formats the timestamp as a date.

Answer (score 1):

I find the airflow docs don't have much detail on this, so this example is mostly from trial and error.

You can access properties of the dags from the `dag` template, for example:

```
import datetime as dt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
from airflow.decorators import task                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
from airflow import DAG                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
with DAG(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    "example",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    catchup=False,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    start_date=dt.datetime(2023,1,1,12),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    schedule="@daily",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
) as dag:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    @task(task_id="print-stuff")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    def print_stuff(**kwargs):  
    # note: kwargs is populated with the templates from 
    # https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#variables                                                    
    # although I didn't find anything in the docs to suggest this would happen                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        logical_date = kwargs['data_interval_start']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        print("logical_date:", logical_date)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        dag = kwargs['dag']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        data_interval = dag.infer_automated_data_interval(logical_date)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        print("start", data_interval.start, "end", data_interval.end)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        next_dagrun = dag.next_dagrun_info(logical_date, restricted=False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        print("next_run start:", next_dagrun.data_interval.start, "next_run_time", next_dagrun.run_after)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    print_stuff()
```

Now I trigger a historical run (with execution date = 2023-05-01, so data_interval_start is 2023-05-01 and data_interval_end is 2023-05-02). The output for the task is:

```
[2023-05-26, 13:20:24 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - logical_date: 2023-05-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2023-05-26, 13:20:24 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - start 2023-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 end 2023-05-02T00:00:00+00:00
[2023-05-26, 13:20:24 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - next_run start: 2023-05-02T00:00:00+00:00 next_run_time 2023-05-03T00:00:00+00:00
```

Let's suppose we set the `restricted=False` parameter to `True`. Now the output is

```
[2023-05-26, 13:29:49 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - logical_date: 2023-05-01T00:00:00+00:00
[2023-05-26, 13:29:49 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - start 2023-05-01T00:00:00+00:00 end 2023-05-02T00:00:00+00:00
[2023-05-26, 13:29:49 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:149} INFO - next_run start: 2023-05-25T00:00:00+00:00 next_run_time 2023-05-26T00:00:00+00:00
```

In other words, it now gets the actual next dag run that will be scheduled, rather than the theoretical next dag run from the date parameter provided into `next_dagrun_info`.